# Different theme of Media module audio player in Firefox and IE and chrome

Tags: 7, entities, media

I installed Media module, and there is a content type for audio files. The Manage display of the audio field is *Audio*. But the player has different themes in different browsers. This is what Firefox displays

[image]

**This is for IE**

[image]

**and it is chrome**

[image]

What is the problem? why do they have not the same theme?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, these are the native displays for the HTML5 `<audio>` element in different browsers. I don't think the Media module has anything to do with it, it probably only displays the markup without adding any theming.